# Weird spacing of Checkbox labels

Tags: asp.net

when I try to create a number of Checkboxes, I have strange spaces inserted:
[image](http://twitpic.com/kezwt/full)

```
<td style="width:85%;white-space:nowrap;" colspan=3>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="rdoSchool" runat="server" Text="School (NSL)" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="rdoSFS" runat="server" Text="Summer Food Service" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="rdoOther" runat="server" Text="Other (Specify)" />&nbsp<asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" Width="125px" runat="server" />
</td>
```

How can I make the label closer to the checkbox?

Comment: and for clarification, that's the horizontal spacing that's off... as in, I'd like the label to be directly after the checkbox, not with that strange gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't default styling, and is most likely caused by your CSS. Use a tool like Firebug (on Firefox) or Developer Tools on IE8 to find the applied CSS rules (Should be <kbd>F12</kbd> either way).

Comment: This was indeed it. I feel pretty foolish, but I was kind of stumped by it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the markup the CheckBox control generates.

... *"Now there's your problem"* - Adam Savage, Mythbusters.

Basically the CheckBox control (along with the RadioButtonList control) generates crappy markup. One way to fix this, is to extend and override the Render method to implement some sensible markup-generation code. Another option is to force the HTML-tables the control generates into place with some clever CSS tricks.